# How to display additional form during views bulk operation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I want to use the **Views Bulk Operations (VBO)** module to get the possibility to select nodes from a view and then do an action on each of them. However, this action requires additional data to be supplied by user, so what I need is to put another form in between VBO submit and the actual action processing.

I am using the *hook_action_info* hook to define my action. However, as I went through the *hook_action_info* [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7) it seems to me that this is not doable using this hook as there is no configuration option to suppress the action bulk ajax update.

Can somebody confirm and/or propose better solution?

In short: User selects nodes from a view using checkboxes, after submitting the form another form appears asking for some more details (having list of nodes as hidden elements in it) and after submitting this one, e-mail is sent per every node. The body of the e-mails is always a combination of node data and the second form data.

Thanks a lot.
Petiar.

Answer (score 1):

So, I decided to forget Views and VBO (no hard feelings) and create my own, custom form. The major thing which actually convinced me that this is not going to be a big issue is the **tableselect** form element type. I think this has been invoked in Drupal 7 and it is magical. At least worth have a look:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect

Thanks everybody for stopping by willing to help.